# Overwrite tailwindcss colors on runtime dynamically in angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, tailwind-css

Multiple companies want their own color styling included inside the angular web application i am currently maintaining. I am using tailwindcss/css for styling and typescript to change the styling depending on what company is currently registered. The approach i am using currently is working as expected, but the problem is that i cannot adjust all components to look appealing since some colors provided just do not match together.

Using [ngClass] or [ngStyle] would take up too much time and for future components all companys would also have to be included everytime. Another approach i found was using css-in-js librarys, but that approach would be similar to [ngClass] and [ngStyle].

This is how i am currently handling the color change on runtime. I have my colors extended inside the tailwindcss config like this:

```
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          primaryBlue: 'var(--primary-blue)',
        },
```

The colors are specified inside the main css file with
`:root { --primary-blue: ##009FE3 }` and i am overwriting the color values like this `:root.company-1 { --primary-blue: #0065AF }`.

And inside the app.component.ts i am changing the color styling like this:

```
changeColorTheme():void{
  if(this.session.currentUser === 'company_1') 
     document.documentElement.classList.add('company-1');
  ...etc
}
```

Thank you for any help or feedback